# Setting of Helm chart to deploy Nodejs service which pushed to Azure Container Registry (ACR)

Tags: node.js, azure, kubernetes-helm

I written a Nodejs service , and build it by docker . Then i pushed it into Azure Container Registry . 
I used Helm to pull Repository from ACR and then deploy to AKS but service not run .
Please tell me some advise.

The code of Helm Value . I thing i have to setting type and port of service.

```py
replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: tungthtestcontainer.azurecr.io/demonode
  tag: latest
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

service:
  name: http
  type: NodePort
  port: 8082
  internalPort: 8082

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths: []

  tls: []

resources: {}

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

Comment: Can you provide the details of the error that deploy the image to AKS? And do you check if your image runs successfully anyway?

Comment: It can deploy by helm and successfull run on local. But on AKS it can not run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure out what happens in that situations it doesn't matter that is helm or a yaml directly with `kubectl apply` o if it's Azure or another provider I recommend you follow the next steps:

- Check the status of the release on helm you can see the status every time you want using `helm status <release-name>`, try to see if the pots are correctly created and the services are also ok.
- Check the deployment with `kubectl describe deployment <deployment-name>`
- Check the pod with `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>`
- Check the pod logs with `kubectl logs -f <pod-name>`

With that, you should be able to find the source problem.

Comment: I don’t sure but when a chage the type of the service. It run.